# How to "install" AS3Commons Logging in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, logging, installation

Hi im pretty new to flash so sorry if the question is stupid, but i just can´t get the as3commons logger to run.

What i did:

```
package {    
    import org.as3commons.logging.ILogger;
    import org.as3commons.logging.LoggerFactory;

        public class "classname" {
            var logger:ILogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("myLogger");

            public function "methodname"() {
                log.info("Some logging message");
            }
        }
    }
```

but i get the error:

> VerifyError: Error #1014: Class org.as3commons.logging::ILogger was not found.

I guess i made some mistake in placing the swc file in my folder structure or something, i tried differnt things but neither worked for me. Has anybody a tutorial or can tell me how to make it run exactly?

**Update:**

Regarding http://arthropod.stopp.se/ it´s true that one can use it easily but i think it´s not too handy to have to start arthropod to see the traces.

Is there a possibility to see them in flash like a normal trace as well?

Comment: @Kev: Please just leave the text in the answers instead of overwriting them.  We have new tools to move answers to comments that only work on the latest revision.  Thanks for flagging this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Not what you're looking for with that logger, but this one...is better and easier :)

http://arthropod.stopp.se/

Comment: thx i know about this tool. it´s true that one can use it easily but i think it´s not too handy to have to start arthropod to see the traces... is there a possibility to see them in flash like a normal trace as well?